# implement reversing title shadow on a button in android

Tags: android

I am trying to reverse the title shadow on a button in android like the implementation in the ios. I have no idea where I should start. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make your own style for button, using Android style Widget.Button as parent. I didn't try it, so I don't know if it private style or not. In your style you can define textShadow attributes. More about styles you can read [there](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)